# If I have the fighter's Extra Attack feature and the warlock's Thirsting Blade eldritch invocation, how many attacks can I make?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, multi-classing, stacking, eldritch-invocations

I am playing a half-orc fighter level 7 and warlock level 3. When I gain a warlock class level, I will gain an Eldritch Invocation, and I will pick Thirsting Blade.

How many attacks can I make, since I have both Thirsting Blade and Extra Attack?

Comment: While [that question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148507/does-this-strict-reading-of-the-rules-allow-both-extra-attack-and-the-thirsting)'s answers may answer this question, that question is about an interaction with Two Weapon Fighting, and is a different question.

Comment: Point of note, the prerequisite for Thirsting Blade is "**5th** level, Pact of the Blade". If you are only level 3 now, you'll need to gain at least 2 level, and be  Pact of the Blade

Comment: @ThomasMarkov the linked answer says "Since you only get Extra Attack as a Warlock if you multiclass and you only get Thirsting Blade as a non-Warlock if you multiclass, this rule always applies and you can never use them together" and quotes the rule "the warlock's eldritch invocation Thirsting Blade doesn't give you additional attacks if you also have Extra Attack". How is this different?

Comment: @enkryptor Duplicate answers does not mean duplicate questions.

Comment: I considered, and rejected, the same duplicate, because really that question seems like an extension of this one—we had just skipped the more basic question originally. I think there’s value in having the basic question addressed first, and the other question can exist as a “but wait, what if you try to get maximally pedantic?”

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Re "*that question seems like an extension of this one*", Aye, the other question presupposes that this question had already been answered. None of its answers answers this question. Don't close questions as a dup of another that merely mentions the answer in the question itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Thirsting Blade does nothing if you have Extra Attack from another class.

The rules for multiclassing (chapter 6 of the *Player's Handbook*) state:

> the warlock's eldritch invocation Thirsting Blade doesn't give you additional attacks if you also have Extra Attack.

So the Thirsting Blade invocation does nothing for you. *So you get to pick a different invocation!*

Comment: Thanks so much! I was using a website, which is an amazing site that has a lot of info but it said nothing of "the warlock's eldritch invocation Thirsting Blade doesn't give you additional attacks if you also have Extra Attack.".

Comment: @MikeZ. It's in the section with the multiclassing rules, that's probably why.

Comment: @MikeZ. The same way that the Monk and Barbarian have their AC set to a specific value rather than getting a bonus to their AC (and so cannot be combined for a multiclass Barbarian/Monk); when you get an extra attack, the ability spells out for you exactly how many attacks you now have, rather than giving you an additional attack that could combine with similar abilities.

Answer (score 29):

Firstly, minor point, you need to be level 5, not 4, to take Thirsting Blade:

> Prerequisite: 5th level, Pact of the Blade feature

And it states:

> You can attack with your pact weapon twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

Extra Attack says the same thing:

> Beginning at 5th Level, you can Attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on Your Turn.

So the limit is still two attacks per turn.

But it is even more explicitly stated in the multiclassing section:

> If you gain the Extra Attack class feature from more than one class, **the features don't add together**. You can't make more than two attacks with this feature unless it says you do (as the fighter's version of Extra Attack does). Similarly, the warlock's eldritch invocation Thirsting Blade doesn't give you additional attacks if you also have Extra Attack.